# Is it possible to "update" iTunes?

Tags: windows, itunes, software-update

Is it actually possible to update iTunes running on Windows 7 Ultimate?

Because every time I've tried, it fails with an error about one service or another. The error is usually related to not having sufficient permissions to modify the service, even though my account is configured as Administrator, and the service varies.

The only way to get the latest version installed consistently is to manually uninstall everything, reboot, then run the installer.

Comment: Can you include the actual error? Technically, the answer to your question is yes: iTunes can be updated using Apple Software Updater for Windows. Some reasons I can think of that would make this not work is if you were under a firewall at work or something similar.

Comment: I've had the same problem for the last couple of years, have to uninstall every component and reinstall them (as per instructions on Apple website) to get this to work. It's a big pain.

Comment: Lately, I've found that if I do a reboot, and update without ever having connected an iDevice, the update works.  If I've had something connected, though, it fails.  Or maybe it's just a problem for people named Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have you installed all the Microsoft security updates to Windows 7 using Windows Update? For instance, are you up to Windows 7 SP1?

Also, have you tried disabling (or "snoozing") your anti-virus software for the time it takes to run the iTunes installer? Conflicts with an anti-virus program would be the most common cause of failing with errors about one service or another.

I have updated iTunes several times on numerous computers running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, and I have never encountered the problems you describe.

Comment: Updates are current, although SP1 is not yet installed.  I'll try to shut down the AV next time.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the iTunes app and redownload it from apple's website. If you just remove the app it should leave your media files untouched but take a backup just in case.

Comment: I think there are a total of 6 separate apps that have to be uninstalled before you can do a clean install, which makes it a bit of a pain.

Comment: 6 separate apps?! iTunes is intentionally for Mac & on mac software is bundled in one package, it shouldn't be that different. Is too much trouble to tell me what are the parts of iTunes you're mentioning?

Comment: The itunes installer for Windows installs itunes, quicktime, apple update service, apple mobile device support service, bonjour service, and apple application support.  The update fails to uninstall one of the services, and which one fails seems to be mostly random.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling iTunes without removing the files? They're supposed to be overwritten.

Comment: Yes - the installer recognizes an existing installation and tries to update, with the same random failure.

Comment: Guess clean install would be the only way out...